# Is there a way to get the raw DOM element from an angular.element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jscolor

[angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)

> All element references in Angular are always wrapped with jQuery or jqLite; they are never raw DOM references.

How can I get the raw DOM element, because I have legacy JS code (jscolor Picker) that needs the raw DOM element?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Found it:

```
ang_element = angular.element(element);
raw_element = ang_element[0];
```

Comment: @fabspro if i am not mistaken angular uses jquery lite so yes.

Comment: "jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal of having a very small footprint."

So basically, they implemented it to be like jQuery, so accessing the result as an array indeed does the same thing as jQuery.

Comment: Jquery you'd typically use .get(0), the array notation is odd and undocumented in the angular jqlite docs, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Kevin The array notation works in jQuery too, though.

Comment: In jQuery, the cleanest way to do this is `$element.get(0)`. Doesn't this exists in angular?