# How to get element with height when element is loaded in angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a textarea, which should be resized to the scrollHeight when it is loaded. I have no problem with key events to resize the textarea like this:

```
$scope.resize= function (event) {
                        //Auto size:
     var element = typeof event === 'object' ? event.target : document.getElementById(event);
     var scrollHeight = element.scrollHeight - 60; 
     element.style.height = scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

But I can not resize it, when the element is loaded. I tried with $element and $element[0], but I noticed that the height of $element is 0. And I don't want to fit the height by window height (I can get window height by $window). Is there any way to get the element.height and element.scrollHeight after loading the element in angular?

Comment: Maybe this way of getting elements would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302493/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-raw-dom-element-from-an-angular-element

Comment: I believe what your looking for is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Comment: I think you should see my answer for angularjs implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize/45947590#45947590

Answer (score 1):

Toss it behind a $timeout as that will allow angular to digest and the element should be created.

```
$timeout(function(){
    //do work on element here
});
```